# Problem with Docker push

Tags: docker

I am trying to push an image to docker-hub to my own repo.  After logging in with my credentials, the upload starts normally; the size is 13GB. The process finishes with no error message, but there is no image upload in docker-hub when I check it. From docker log I see:

```
  Aug 12 10:29:51 cmsbuild7-01 dockerd: time="2016-08-12T10:29:51.091865728+02:00" level=error msg="Upload failed, retrying: blob upload unknown"
  Aug 12 10:29:57 cmsbuild7-01 kernel: XFS (dm-1): Mounting V4 Filesystem
  Aug 12 10:29:57 cmsbuild7-01 kernel: XFS (dm-1): Ending clean mount
  Aug 12 10:33:28 cmsbuild7-01 dockerd: time="2016-08-12T10:33:28.360053301+02:00" level=error msg="Not continuing with push after error: context canceled"
```

Any thoughts?

Docker info:

```
   [root@cmsbuild7-01 ~]# docker info
   Containers: 0
   Running: 0
   Paused: 0
   Stopped: 0
   Images: 30
   Server Version: 1.12.0
  Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-252:32-30670853-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
  Base Device Size: 42.95 GB
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Data file: /dev/loop0
  Metadata file: /dev/loop1
  Data Space Used: 29.99 GB
  Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
  Data Space Available: 77.38 GB
  Metadata Space Used: 20.15 MB
  Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
  Metadata Space Available: 2.127 GB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Deferred Removal Enabled: false
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
```